# Distinguish i3 MK3 from i3 MK3S

Tags: prusa-i3

I have a Prusa i3 MK3 or maybe it was upgraded to a i3 MK3S.

How can I figure out?

The [description of the upgrade kit](https://shop.prusa3d.com/en/original-prusa-i3-mk3s/1390-original-prusa-i3-mk3-to-mk3s-upgrade-kit.html) talks about

- the SuperPINDA (how is it different from the old one?)
- a number of small changes (which?)
- improved plastic parts (which parts, how are they different?)
- metal clips (where to look for them?)
- a number of minor changes to the extruder plastic parts (which ones, before and after?)

I'd like to figure that out without taking the printer apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Left right]

[image: Filament sensors]

The MK3 has 4 pins on the filament sensor, the MK3S has only 3 pins. While you need to take the extruder apart to see that, you can also have a look at the cable instead:

[image: Filament sensor cable]

Matching the sensor, the MK3 has a 4 strand wire including blue and the MK3S has a 3 strand cable without blue.

[image: Bearing clips]

Looking under the heatbed, you'll find the MK3 bearings are fixed with U-bolts while the MK3S has broader bearing clips.

Comment: You list three differences. Did you ever find out the differences mentioned in your other sub-questions, such as the minor changes to the plastic parts of the extruder?

Comment: @Greenonline: since I don't own a MK3S, I wasn't able to check for differences

Answer (score 4):

On the LCD, the MK3 will show **Original Prusa MK3 OK**, while the MK3S/+ will show **Original Prusa MK3S OK**. This will only work if you have the stock firmware installed.